# Can I make this macro more efficient or faster?

Tags: vba, excel

I am brand new to coding. This macro runs slow and I'm hopeful that someone can help me clean it up.  Thanks in advance for your help.

I developed the code to update my company's "Call Router" worksheet with new leads purchased from an outside source. The leads come to us in raw format in a worksheet called Fresh Agents Leads. Once the "Fresh Agent Leads" sheet is copied into the "MSS Call Routing Master List" file which houses the "Call Router" Worksheet, the macro reduces the raw data so that the parts we do not use are eliminated.  It then re-formats what remains to match the formatting of the Old Call Router Worksheet and merges the two.  It then renames the new Master sheet to Call Router.

The code is designed to start inside the workbook that houses the Fresh Agent Leads Sheet. The user is instructed to have both the Fresh Agents Leads File and the MSS Call Routing Master List opened on the desktop before executing the code.

```
    Sheets("Fresh Agent Leads").Select
    Sheets("Fresh Agent Leads").Copy After:=Workbooks( _
        "MSS Call Routing Master List.xlsx").Sheets(1)
    Columns("F:F").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Columns("F:F").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("C:C").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("E:E").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("G:S").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Columns("C:C").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("C1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(RIGHT(RC[1],4))"
    Range("C1").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("C1:C1048575")
    Range("C1:C1048575").Select

    Sheets("Call Router").Select
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Fresh Agent Leads").Select
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.Run "PERSONAL.xlsb!MergeIdenticalWorksheets"
    Columns("C:C").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "0000"
    Range("A:A,B:B,F:F").Select
    Range("F1").Activate
    Selection.ColumnWidth = 14
    Columns("E:E").Select
    Selection.ColumnWidth = 25
    Columns("C:C").Select
    Selection.ColumnWidth = 8.29
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.RowHeight = 30
    With Selection
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = True
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.Font
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Columns("D:D").Select
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Range("E2").Select
    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
    Sheets(Array("Call Router", "Fresh Agent Leads")).Select
    Sheets("Call Router").Activate
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Delete
    Sheets("Master").Select
    Sheets("Master").Name = "Call Router"
    Range("C23").Select
    ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried looking at how expensive this line is? Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("C1:C1048575")

Comment: i agree with J Trana. But most of your code needs refining. I didn't see your `Variable` declaration but i am guessing you declared none. Also you use `Select` too much that it is affecting the speed of your code. Try to adapt to what's discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select) regarding avoiding select and improving your code speed. if you came across things you cannot comprehend, update your question and paste your code, error and or dificulties encountered.

Comment: A more representative title would help a lot.

Comment: L42 is right. Also, you want to avoid referring to the ActiveSheet object. Either tell it exactly where to go with `ThisWorkBook.Sheets("SheetNameHere")` or if you are looping, declare it first. As far as the Autofill part goes, have you tried looking up how to find the last row? `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Reference").Range("A:A").Rows.Count.End(xlUp).Row` instead of the very last row possible should speed things up.

Comment: Right away, it's not clear if this code is being executed in the workbook where `Fresh Agent Leads` is found or in the `MSS Call Routing Master List` workbook. I can see in the beginning that you copying FAL to another workbook, but it's not clear if the operations are being carried out in the source or the target (even though you said that you work on them, we need on which workbook this 'work' is happening). ;)

Comment: Thanks so much for your help J Trana, L42, Sancho.s, PermaNoob, and BK201. My Rookie colors gave me a chuckle after reading your comments here.  L42, I gave the article you mentioned a good look and will study up some more. Will make corrections mentioned in these comments and will continue re-posting. I hope I did an okay job of clarifying my question BK201. I greatly appreciate this feedback. Thanks so much.

Comment: @Thomas: No worries. It is very rare that this tag gets really eager newbies nowadays. ;) Read through my entire post below. It will help you a LOT. Besides best practices, there are methods there that will surely improve your code. ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A few tips:

1. Avoid `.Select` and `.Activate` as much as possible. Recording macros is a good start to VBA, but the first big step is leaving the "comfort zone" provided by these properties. In the beginning, they're good, but they're bound to create problems in the long run.
2. Read up on the following "basic" procedures: copying/pasting/inserting ranges, creating/deleting sheets, and determining the last rows/columns of a sheet or range that has relevant data. These three are your bestfriends. By learning these three by heart, you can manipulate a lot in Excel VBA.
3. After (2), start learning how to dimension variables and/or objects. Setting the jargon aside, this is basically just akin to giving each important thing you're working on "nicknames". Say you're working on 3 sheets. You don't want to keep on referring to `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")` and so on and on. You'd much rather want `Sh1` or `Sh2` instead.
4. Learn how to bunch similar procedures together using `Union`, `With`, or the like. This goes hand in hand with (1) above. You'll see an example later on this.
5. `Application.ScreenUpdating` - one of the best time-shaving tricks in Excel VBA.

Now, a few samples:

**(1) Avoiding `.Select` || Learning to use the very nice `.Copy` one-liner**

This part...

```
Range("A1").Select
Selection.Copy
Columns("F:F").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

...can be reduced to:

```
Range("A1").Copy Range("F:F")
```

From four lines to just one. And it's much more readable. The second code snippet aboves basically reads, "Copy A1's value to the whole F column". Note that that's actually quite memory intensive, as in Excel 2010, you're actually pasting to a million and more rows with that command. Better be specific, like `Range("F1:F1000")`.

**(2) Bunching commands together**

Bunching commands together in "written" VBA is different from the way you do it in macros. Since macros are recorded, everything is based on real time modifications. In "written" VBA, you can specify an action that will allow you to apply a single action on multiple objects. Let's say for example you want to delete Columns A and C while shifting all relevant data to the left.

When recording a macro to do this, you can select both A and C and delete them at the same time. However, most beginners take the safe path and record the deletion of columns *one at a time* which--while safe--is highly counterintuitive. Selecting both before deleting is the best option.

In written VBA, the second method above is a massive no-no (or at least, it's not the norm). Unless there's a specific and necessary reason, bunching similar commands together is the convention as it both eliminates error to a large degree and is not resource intensive.

In your code...

```
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Columns("C:C").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Columns("E:E").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Columns("G:S").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
```

... is such a pain to read. We don't know why there are two deletions there, we don't know for sure where the data in Column S originally was, etc, etc. In instances like this, determining ahead of time the ranges you want to delete and executing the deletion is the perfect way.

Let's assume for example's sake that you want to delete the columns A, C, E, and F to O. A neat approach like follows will pull this off quite quickly and efficiently.

```
Union(Range("A:A"),Range("C:C"),Range("E:E"),Range("F:O")).Delete
```

`Union` is one of your early bestfriends. As with set notation in math, ranges you specify are put together into a set of ranges together and are actioned upon at the same time (in this case, `.Delete`d at the same time). Since the default shift is to the left, we can altogether remove the `Shift:=xlToLeft` line (another nifty VBA fact).

**(3) `With` - one thing you cannot live without**

At this point, you might be thinking, what about multiple actions on these ranges? We've only done single actions on multiple ranges and not the other way around. This is the point where `With` comes in. In this context, `With` will be used only on `Ranges` but it can be used on almost anything in VBA. Objects, ranges, external applications, etc. I will not delve on this, but suffice to say that using `With` is like using an anchor on something you want to work on with a few procedures.

In your code, we find...

```
Columns("C:C").Select
Selection.ColumnWidth = 8.29
With Selection
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
    .WrapText = False
    .Orientation = 0
    .AddIndent = False
    .IndentLevel = 0
    .ShrinkToFit = False
    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
    .MergeCells = False
End With
Rows("1:1").Select
Selection.RowHeight = 30
With Selection
    .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
    .WrapText = True
    .Orientation = 0
    .AddIndent = False
    .ShrinkToFit = False
    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
    .MergeCells = False
End With
```

... which can be reduced to:

```
With Columns("C:C")
    .ColumnWidth = 8.29
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
End With
With Rows(1:1)
    .RowHeight = 30
    .WrapText = True
End With
```

Basically, we did two things here. First, we anchored on Column C, and did two actions on it: set the column width, then the horizontal alignment. After anchoring to Column C and modifying it, we change the anchor to the whole of row 1 and we modify its height and set it to wrap text to cell width. From 24 lines, we've reduced that macro block to just 8 lines. How's that for brevity? :)

Why did I make without the other lines? As in the previous example (`Union`), we can make do with some lines that are either the default value anyway or are not modified. There will be exceptions to these, but they will be far and few and are a bit off your level for now. You'll get there.

**(4) Creating/modifying sheets and avoiding `.Activate`, and a touch on dimensions**

One of the pitfalls of beginners in VBA is that they use `ActiveWorkbook`, `ActiveSheet`, and `.Activate` a lot. This is not bad per se, but it's not good either. It's convenient to use, but it will cause a myriad of headaches if you incorporate it in really complex subroutines and functions.

To combat this, we first go into the idea of dimensioning or qualifying your objects. This is done by first declaring a keyword and then a data type. I will not delve into this further, as there are lots of VBA tutorials you can read for this, so I'll just point out some important ones.

Let's say you're working on two **open** workbooks. We can create a "nickname" for each of them so you can refer to them without having to type whole lines of reference.

```
Dim SourceWbk As Workbook
Dim TargetWbk As Workbook
```

The two lines above read as, "`SourceWbk`/`TargetWbk` is my nickname and I am dimensioned as a workbook, so I'll be expecting to be referred to a workbook". Now that we've created dimensions for them, we can point them to what they will stand for.

```
Set SourceWbk = ThisWorkbook
Set TargetWbk = Workbooks("I AM THE MASTER REPORT")
```

Note the "=" here. Now, we've basically declared that from now on, `SourceWbk` is going to refer to the workbook containing this code, and `TargetWbk` is going to refer to the ***open*** workbook named "I AM THE MASTER REPORT". Now let's look at the simple act of copying a sheet from `SourceWbk` to `TargetWbk`.

```
SourceWbk.Sheets("Sheet1").Copy After:=TargetWbk.Sheets("Sheet1")
```

Looks familiar? That's because this is pretty much the same as this recorded block of your code:

```
Sheets("Fresh Agent Leads").Select
Sheets("Fresh Agent Leads").Copy After:=Workbooks( _
    "MSS Call Routing Master List.xlsx").Sheets(1)
```

Now, you can go one step further and name the sheets themselves, then copy them. Example follows:

```
Dim FAL As Worksheet 'Expects a worksheet.
Dim LastSheet As Worksheet

Set FAL = SourceWbk.Sheets("Fresh Agent Leads")
Set LastSheet = TargetWbk.Sheets("Sheet1") 'You can use a number index or specific name

FAL.Copy After:=LastSheet
```

At this point the code is very, very short and sweet already. No hassles, and the only effort you actually need is to remember what the "nicknames" refer to. Take note that there are specific words you should **NOT** be using as variable names. As much as possible, make it personalized but reasonable. Simply naming a sheet as `Sh` is good but it gets you nowhere in a file with 100 sheets each with different purposes.

**(5) The `Application` Trickbook**

In Excel VBA, there are a few things you can manipulate to increase the efficiency of your code. After all is said and done, a macro is just a repeated action. Running a recorded or a written one both will take you through the actions. `.Select` will select specific ranges and you'll see them get selected. `.Activate` will do the same, more or less. `.Copy` will show you those "ants" and the highlights they leave behind. All these contribute to a longer and often sloppy visual execution of the code. Herein steps the `ScreenUpdating` "trick".

Mind you, it's not really a trick. Most people consider them highly important parts of their code, but their inclusion into "layman" VBA modules are nonetheless helpful. One of the best practices is setting `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` at the beginning of a subroutine then setting it back to `True` at the end.

`ScreenUpdating` will "freeze" your screen, making everything happen without you seeing them. You won't see items getting copied or ranges getting selected. You won't see closed workbooks being opened and closed. While this only affects Excel when you call it, it's nonetheless invaluable.

A quick and dirty list (do not use this as an absolute reference!) of `Application` tricks:

- .ScreenUpdating (False/**True**): Eliminates the visual updating of Excel when `False`. Absolutely necessary when copy-pasting or deleting rows.
- .Calculation (**xlCalculationAutomatic**/xlCalculationSemiautomatic/xlCalculationManual): Similar to the `Formulas > Calculation Options` ribbon function, setting this to Manual will suspend all calculations. Highly recommended especially when you're updating ranges that are depended on by loads of `VLOOKUP` or `INDEX` formulas.
- .EnableEvents(False/**True**): Disables triggering event based procedures. A bit advanced, but suffice to say that if you've got some automatic macro triggering on event-based changes, this will suspend them in favor of the current running macro.

There are loads of others and it will be to your best interest to learn most of them. ;)

***THE BIG FINALE***

Here's a sample code taken from your recorded macro that uses all the above techniques and takes into consideration the procedures you executed on your macro. ***This is not your whole code.*** Read this, test this, modify this and you'll improve a lot in a day.

```
Sub RefinedCode()

    Dim SourceWbk As Workbook, TargetWbk As Workbook
    Dim FALSht As Worksheet, FALSht2 As Worksheet, MasterSht As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'We won't see the copy-paste and column deletion happening but they will happen. 

    Set SourceWbk = ThisWorkbook
    Set TargetWbk = Workbooks("MSS Call Routing Master List")
    Set FALSht = SourceWbk.Sheets("Fresh Agent Leads")

    With TargetWbk          
        Set MasterSht = .Sheets("Master") 'Basically reads as Set MasterSht = TargetWbk.Sheets("Master")
        FAL.Copy After:= .Sheets(1)
        Set FALSht2 = .Sheets("Fresh Agent Leads")
    End With

    With FALSht2
        Union(.Range("A:A"),.Range("C:C"),.Range("E:O")).Delete
        With .Rows(1)
            .RowHeight = 30
            .WrapText = True
        End With
        .Range("A1").Copy .Range("F1:F100")
    End With

    MasterSht.Name = "Call Router"
    TargetWbk.Save
    SourceWbk.Close

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True 'Return to default setting.

End Sub
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Terrific contribution to a newbie's learning journey. It's a good thing when people like you have "too much time on their hands". A couple of things I always add: Must use `Option Explicit` to catch typos in variables (and generally get better error checking during compilation); use specific types (rather than Variant) whenever possible - much faster, and don't forget `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`. That one alone will save a TON of speed especially when you are changing formatting etc.

Comment: @Floris: I was actually a bit torn about including those in the above. First, the text is too much as it is. And `Option Explicit` for a real beginner is a bit too intimidating. It will point out error after error and can hamper the code. For most of us, debugging is like 90% of the work, but for beginners, this is something they will eventually encounter. The `Application` "tricks", that's for another time. Hahaha. But, yes, let me put in at least `.ScreenUpdating` since this is virtually a necessity! :)

Comment: Meh, expanded it a bit more than just `.ScreenUpdating`. :)

Comment: WOW! BK201, just saw your post here.  Thank you SO much.  I will be chewing on what you've shared for a nice long while.  While the latter half of @Floris post will take me a bit of time to comprehend, I second her on the "terrific contribution...." Many Thanks.

Comment: @Thomas: No worries. If this was helpful, kindly accept it as an answer. Let us know if you've got other issues. ;)

Comment: @Floris I like to use `Option Explicit` but it's not a good practice. You can make a good code without using it, go to Script Lua language for example. You don't see variable typecast and it's not a problem.

Comment: @BK201 I'll put this question in my favorite to aways redirect noobies' questions to this answer.

Comment: @BK201 Maybie you should mention about DoEvent in (5).

Comment: @Makah - you don't have to typecast when you have `Option Explicit` - just declare the variable. It helps catch typos (you assigned `myvariable=1` then type `If myvaraible =1` - without option explicit it will quietly fail... And the speed penalty for variants can be significant, especially in tight loops.

Comment: @Floris I agree with you, but it is the way that script languages work. Some people think that it is a good thing.

Comment: Remember the original question was "how do I make this better"... Not "what can I get away with". I just gave my opinion based on more than 30 years of experience with "script languages" (yes including excel 4 macros...)

Answer (score 0):

I always use the following line

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

to turn off the screen updates which make the macro run much faster. Just add it in the beginning of your macro(s).

Comment: ... And add `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` at the end. This way, the screen will update.

Comment: @BK201 It is automatically turned back on at the end of a program.

Answer (score -1):

Awesome help here. I wish there was an easy way to stop the flicker when changing sheets ... Application.ScreenUpdating does not fully eliminate that in excel 2013 anyway.

Comment: This should be posted as a comment, not an answer since it doesn't actually answer the question.