# VBA: Dynamic Mapping Column Headers with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, visual-studio-code, microsoft-dynamics

I am trying to map columns from one worksheet to another before copying the columns. I found some useful codes here especially by @Nulldev ([mapping column headers from one sheet to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21130328/mapping-column-headers-from-one-sheet-to-another)) in this discussion.

However, in my case I receive many schedules with different headers spellings/names (the content in the columns are the same), that I need to import into my own template.

This is the code i have tried:

```
Sub ModdedMap()

    Dim Sh1 As Worksheet, Sh2 As Worksheet, Sh3 As Worksheet
    Dim HeadersOne As Range, HeadersTwo As Range
    Dim hCell As Range

    With ThisWorkbook
        Set Sh1 = .Sheets("Sheet1") 'Modify as necessary.
        Set Sh2 = .Sheets("Sheet2") 'Modify as necessary.
        Set Sh3 = .Sheets("Interface") 'Modify as necessary.
    End With

    Set HeadersOne = Sh3.Range("A1:A" & Sh3.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each hCell In HeadersOne

        SCol = GetColMatched(Sh1, hCell.Value)
        TCol = GetColMatched(Sh2, hCell.Offset(0, 1).Value)
        LRow = GetLastRowMatched(Sh1, hCell.Value)

        For Iter = 2 To LRow
            Sh2.Cells(Iter, TCol).Value = Sh1.Cells(Iter, SCol).Value
        Next Iter

    Next hCell

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Function GetLastRowMatched(Sh As Worksheet, Header As String) As Long
    ColIndex = Application.Match(Header, Sh.Rows(1), 0)
    GetLastRowMatched = Sh.Cells(Rows.Count, ColIndex).End(xlUp).Row
End Function

Function GetColMatched(Sh As Worksheet, Header As String) As Long
    ColIndex = Application.Match(Header, Sh.Rows(1), 0)
    GetColMatched = ColIndex
End Function
```

In worksheet 1

```
  A                 B            C 
1 applicationname applicationid number 
2 applcation1          1          123 
3 applcation2          2          454 
4 applcation3          3          897
```

On my Mapping Sheet

```
     A                       B
 1   Application Name        App Name
 2   Application ID          AppID
 3   Technology              Tech
 4   Business Criticality    Bus Criticality
 5   IT Owner                IT Admin
 6   Business Owner        BusOwner
 7.  Application number.    App ID
 8   IT User.       IT Admin
```

In worksheet 2

```
  A                 B            C 
1  appid           num        appname              
2   1              123        applcation1          
3   2              454        applcation2          
4   3              897        applcation3
```

On my Interface sheet, you will noticed I pointed IT User = "IT Owner" and IT Admin = "IT Owner" too.
I also pointed Application ID and Application number = App ID

**I will like the code to check Worksheet 1 if the header reads Application number or Application ID or any other thing set to equal "App ID", it should extract the column to the worksheet 2. And move on to the next Header**

Thank you

Comment: How is your question different from the linked one?

Comment: It is different, The code does not allow me to equal different headers to the same output.

Comment: Make it a comma delimited list, split on the comma and loop through the resulting array

Comment: Thank you @Warcupine, I am new to VBA. Kindly direct me on how to apply your recommendation.