# Copy results from one workbook to another

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

My code takes a while to run. I would like to copy results from one sheet (wbkorigin) to several sheets (many wbkdestination). I've tried it for one sheet to another ( 1 to 1) and it really takes a while to run. Can you help me optimize my code? thanks!!

```
Option Explicit
Sub update()
    Dim wkbkorigin As Workbook
    Dim wkbkdestination As Workbook
    Dim originsheet As Worksheet
    Dim destsheet As Worksheet

    Set wkbkorigin = ActiveWorkbook

    Set wkbkdestination = Workbooks.Open("link to worksheet")

    Set originsheet = wkbkorigin.Worksheets("sheet1")
    Set destsheet = wkbkdestination.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    originsheet.Range("D4:Q5").Copy
    destsheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial
    wkbkdestination.Close SaveChanges:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: The code you have is exactly what I'd use as well, except for one thing: `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` after your declaration area should work wonders. See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20738373/can-i-make-this-macro-more-efficient-or-faster/20754562#20754562) for an explanation, #5 to be exact.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will accelerate a bit:

```
Sub update()

    'Put calculation to xlCalculationManual and screenupdating to Off
    Dim calcState As XlCalculation
    calcState = Application.Calculation
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Dim wkbkorigin As Workbook
    Dim wkbkdestination As Workbook
    Dim originsheet As Worksheet
    Dim destsheet As Worksheet

    Set wkbkorigin = ActiveWorkbook

    Set wkbkdestination = Workbooks.Open("link to worksheet")

    Set originsheet = wkbkorigin.Worksheets("sheet1")
    Set destsheet = wkbkdestination.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    'Copy/Paste in one step
    originsheet.Range("D4:Q5").Copy destsheet.Range("A1")

    Application.Calculate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = calcState

    wkbkdestination.Close SaveChanges:=True

End Sub
```

1) Put calculation to manual;
2) ScreenUpdating to off;
3) Copy/Paste in one step since you don't use the pastespecial options (I don't think this line will speed up the process but it is cleaner)

Comment: If some of the steps I added are unclear, just ask :)

Comment: Is it possible to do the same without opening the file (wrkbkdestination) : it could also save some time... ?

Comment: @YasmineNouri; No, it is not possible to alter workbook data without opening it.

Comment: too bad... So if i have to export results from one workbook to several workbooks, it is going to open every workbook... It will take a lot of time.