# Syntax for Do Until Loop

Tags: excel, vba

What is the correct syntax for a Do Until Loop? This is my first try attempting and I am getting an error message that says "Loop without Do". Here is what I have:

```
Dim i As Long

Do

For i = 3 To 93

Sheets("Analysis").Select
Range("B" & i).Copy
Range("R3").PasteSpecial

Sheets("Analysis").Select
Range("Q3").Copy
Range("G" & i).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Loop Until Sheets("Analysis").Range("L1") < 50
```

Comment: The code is just missing the `Next` before the `Loop Until`

Answer (score 1):

Although I can't figure out what you are trying to acomplish with you loop, the code should be changed to the following in order to make it "correct".

```
Dim i As Long
Do         
    For i = 3 To 93
        Sheets("Analysis").Select
        Range("B" & i).Copy
        Range("R3").PasteSpecial

        Sheets("Analysis").Select
        Range("Q3").Copy
        Range("G" & i).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Next i
Loop Until Sheets("Analysis").Range("L1") < 50
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code could use some real clean-up.

```
Dim i As Long

With Sheets("Analysis")
    Do Until .Range("L1").Value < 50
        For i = 3 To 93
            .Range("B" & i).Copy .Range("R3")
            .Range("Q3").Copy
            .Range("G" & i).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Next i
    Loop
End With
```

A couple of things. First, make sure that there's a mechanism somewhere that reduces the value in `.Range("L1")` to less than `50`. Otherwise, this runs in an infinite loop (because you can't complete the condition to make it stop).

Second, make sure that your `For` loops are closed with `Next`. Either `Next` or `Next x` where `x` is the iterator variable you defined should work (in your case, `x` is `i`).

Third, read up on the differences of `Do While-Loop`, `Do Until-Loop`, `Do-Loop While`, and `Do-Loop Until`. `Until` and `While` are pretty self-explanatory. The placement of the condition is a bit of a difficulty for those beginning with loops and should be mastered without question. One really clear explanation can be found [here](http://www.homeandlearn.org/excel_vba_do_loops.html).

Fourth, use `With` for sequential or simultaneous actions on a single object. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20754562/2548721) out for samples and explanations (check section **(3)**).

Hope this helps.

Comment: actually, this line make no sence to me: `.Range("B" & i).Copy .Range("R3")` :) we could just write `.Range("B93").Copy .Range("R3")`  without `For i = 3 To 93` loop. The same thing here: `.Range("G3:G93").Value=.Range("Q3").Value`

Comment: I was inclined to make the same observation. The issue I have with this code is not so much the loop but the... *unorthodox* copying. Obviously, overwriting `.Range(R3)` over and over again escapes me. But even so, I see nothing that changes `L1` as well. Perhaps OP is executing this inside a called sub and an outer sub decreases `L1`, etc. We never know until OP really comments on whether the above works or not... And I've got my guess it won't. Lol. :D If he just wants to transfer values, I believe your comment is the best as well. :)