# Add a variable within Do Until loop

Tags: excel, vba

Can someone explain how to add a variable within a Do Until Loop? I can't quite get mine to work. I am getting an error that says "Next without for". Here is what I have so far:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Dim i As Long
For i = 5 To 6

Do Until Sheets("Analysis").Range("L1") < 50 And Sheets("Analysis").Range("N1") < 250000 And Sheets("Analysis").Range("AB" & i) > 0.05


Next i


Application.Calculate

Loop
```

Thank you!

Comment: see correct sintax here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22071052/syntax-for-do-until-loop

Answer (score 1):

You are overlapping your loops - I put the **Do** loop **inside** the **For** loop below:

```
Dim i As Long
For i = 5 To 6

Do Until Sheets("Analysis").Range("L1") < 50 And Sheets("Analysis").Range("N1") < 250000 And Sheets("Analysis").Range("AB" & i) > 0.05
Application.Calculate

Loop
Next i
```