# Run-time error '13': Type mismatch error code

Tags: excel, runtime-error, vba

I'm using the following code to create a column of data which i can use as a filter from a pivot table.

the code works but it flags a  "Run-time error '13':  Type mismatch" code error. can anyone help me change the code to eliminate the error message.

here is the code i'm using.

```
    Sub negativepivot()

        Sheets("owssvr").Select
        Columns("W:W").Select
        Selection.ClearContents
        Range("W2").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Table_owssvr[@[Count Zero]]"
        Range("W2").Select
        Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("W2:W230"), Type:=xlFillDefault
        Range("W2:W230").Select
        ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-230
        Range("W1").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Negative results"

    For Each Cell In Range("W2:W230")
    If Cell.Value <= 0 Then
    Cell.Value = "Negative"
    Else
    Cell.Value = Cell.Value
    End If
    Next
    End Sub
```

Comment: Which line is highlighted when it throws the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid using `.Select` or `.Activate` as much as possible. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20738373/can-i-make-this-macro-more-efficient-or-faster/20754562#20754562) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10717999/2548721) for other methods and for reasons. Also, in the former link, check the usage of `With`.

Your code looks programmatically correct, so try improving the overall style. VBA is touchy to a degree.

```
Sub NegativePivotMod()

    With Sheets("owssvr")

        .Range("W:W").ClearContents

        With .Range("W2")
            .FormulaR1C1 = "=Table_owssvr[@[Count Zero]]"
            .AutoFill Destination:=.Range("W2:W230"), Type:=xlFillDefault
        End With

        Range("W1").FormulaR1C1 = "Negative results"

        For Each Cell In .Range("W2:W230")
            If Cell.Value < 0 Then
                Cell.Value = "Negative"
            End If
        Next

    End With

End Sub
```

Let us know if this helps.