# VBA - How to export range to Image - MAC

Tags: excel, vba, image, macos, export

I'm trying to export a range of cells as Image from Excel 2016 (16.13) in a Mac (High Sierra).

So far this is what i managed to put together...

```
Sub Export() 

Dim oWs As Worksheet
Dim oRng As Range
Dim oChrtO As ChartObject
Dim lWidth As Long, lHeight As Long
'
Set oWs = ActiveSheet
Set oRng = oWs.Range("C8:I20")
'
oRng.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlPicture
lWidth = oRng.Width
lHeight = oRng.Height
'
Set oChrtO = oWs.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=0, Top:=0, Width:=lWidth, Height:=lHeight)
'
oChrtO.Activate
With oChrtO
.ShapeRange.Line.Visible = msoFalse
.Height = oRng.Height
.Width = oRng.Width
.Chart.Paste
.Chart.Export FileName:="Report.png", Filtername:="JPG"
End With
'
oChrtO.Delete
'
End Sub
```

I still have the following problems:

1-Automatically file is saved into /Users/MyAccount/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Excel/Data/ and I need to save it into a specific folder on my Desktop

2-"Small cosmetic issue", left and top edge are grey (file.png)- [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNe26.png)

Any Suggestion?

EDIT:
I also tried to add:

```
Dim fileAccessGranted As Boolean
Dim filePermissionCandidates
'Create an array with file paths for which permissions are needed
filePermissionCandidates = Array("/Users/<MyAccount>/Desktop/")
'Request Access from User
fileAccessGranted = GrantAccessToMultipleFiles(filePermissionCandidates)
```

and

```
.Chart.Export FileName:="/Users/<MyAccount>/Desktop/Case.jpg", Filtername:="JPG"
```

resulting in the Error "Run-Time error '70' Permission denied".

Comment: Have a look at how I used a specific path in this macro... : https://stackoverflow.com/q/50776026/4961700

Comment: I edit my post with the information you suggested. Now I got a "Run-Time error '70' Permission denied"

Comment: Have a look on this site for some other answers, I found this one very helpful : https://stackoverflow.com/a/20754562/4961700

Comment: Nice tips, but still cannot find a solution...